# how can I implement text-2-speech function in iOS app via firemonkey?

Tags: ios, firemonkey, text-to-speech

I have a iOS APP needs to spell out the words or phrase so the listener can type in the words they hear. How to implement text2speech with Delphi Firemonkey?

tried searching around the net, none useful found.

Comment: This question is far too broad for SO. Please post what you have tried and a specific issue you are having.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Start by looking at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer then consult other projects that use iOS native libs on how to include them into Delphi. Should not be that hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from EMBT, I found a solution from https://blog.grijjy.com/2017/01/09/cross-platform-text-to-speech/ It is a good solution to mine. Just wondered why EMBT NOT do this? Encapsulating such simple and important function to a special group directly from iOS/OSX foundations is easy,handy but important for developers using Delphi. FireMonkey has no such functions. Don't know what to say about this. EMBT seems having difficulty to find the key point as always.